# Use content of binary as string in DataFrame in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I created a DataFrame from an existing table where two columns are stored as binary. For the further processing I need the binary-content as string.

Example:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+
|              DB_KEY|          PARENT_KEY|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|[00 50 56 88 0A]    |[00 50 56 88 12]    |

Schema:
root
 |-- DB_KEY: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- PARENT_KEY: binary (nullable = true)
```

Content of binary should be used as string like:

```
DB_KEY = "005056880A"
PARENT_KEY = "0050568812"
```

Can you please give me any hints how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried to [`hex()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=functions#pyspark.sql.functions.hex) your binary fields?

```
scala> val df = spark.sql("select unhex('005056880A') as db_key")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [db_key: binary]

scala> df.withColumn("db_key_string", hex($"db_key")).show(false)
+----------------+-------------+
|db_key          |db_key_string|
+----------------+-------------+
|[00 50 56 88 0A]|005056880A   |
+----------------+-------------+
```